# Is there a method to isolate moving entity using "reverse exposure" instead of using green screen?

Tags: editing, software, post-production, greenscreen, digital-recording

### Background

I am looking into ways to isolate moving entities, such as person, or objects on a relatively static background without using green screen, due to cost and location restriction.

### What it's used for?

Isolating moving objects, but particularly choreography, or at least a concept of it, where a single person takes multiple takes and act like a group dance.

### What I've looked into

I have "some" knowledge regarding photography, and it is to my understanding that `Long Exposure` is used by some photographers to capture a static object in a relatively dynamic environment by blurring or out-right "ignoring" the non-static entities in the image.

What I think would fit well for the scenario I need is something like `Long Exposure`, but inverse, some kind of Inverse Exposure. That way I won't need to consider green screen or post-production much, and slice and arrange footages in a way that it becomes good and seamless enough.

#### Additional Info

The camera will always be static on recording, so some method where it take the initial sceen image and remove any background from that image is welcome, and if it exist, I would like to know the application.